# Updateview with dynamic form_class

Tags: python, django, django-views

I would like to dynamically change the `form_class` of an `UpdateView` CBV in Django 1.6.

I've tried to do this using the get_context_data(), but that didn't help since the form is already initialized. So it will need to happen during `__init__`, I guess. 
Here's what I've tried on `__init__`:

```
class UpdatePersonView(generic.UpdateView):

    model = Person
    form_class = ""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdatePersonView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        person = Person.objects.get(id=self.get_object().id)
        if not person.somefield:
            self.form_class = OneFormClass
        elif person.somefield:
            self.form_class = SomeOtherFormClass
```

I'm stuck with a `'UpdatePersonView' object has no attribute 'kwargs'` error message when executing `person = Person.objects.get(id=self.get_object().id)`.

When manually specifying the id (e.g. `id=9`), then the setup works.

How can I get the args/kwargs inside the **init** method that I'm overriding? Particularly I would need access to the `pk`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should simply override [`get_form_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_form_class).

(Also I'm not sure why you're querying for `person`: that object is the same is `self.get_object()` already, so there's no point getting the ID of that then querying again.)

```
def get_form_class(self):
    if self.object.somefield:
        return OneFormClass
    else:
        return SomeOtherFormClass
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that was easier than I thought.