# Django conditional field display on form

Tags: django

I am trying to make a simple form, that conditionally shows the `website` input field based on the value of another database field (that is not on the form) `status`. For the sake of this process the `status` field is not editable by the user, just by the admin. Both fields are in the same table: `profile`.

After working at this for a while I copped-out and just did the conditional hiding and showing on the template. But, I realise this is the unsophisticated method, and would like to improve it.

What I tried so far in `forms.py`:

```
class WebsiteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        
        fields = (
            'e-mail',
            'website',
        )

        if Profile.status == 'personal' :
            exclude = ('website',)
```

This method in `forms.py` works effectively, in that I can conditionally show and hide the field if I use test comparitors in the `if` statement like:

```
if 1 == 1:
```

or

```
if 1 != 1:
```

But, I cannot get an effective test using the field `Profile.status`, the value in the field seems to be unavailable at the point the `if` test in `forms.py` is performed.

If I use `print(Profile.status)` I get the following output in the terminal: `user__profile__status__isnull`, so I think this means that I am at least testing the correct field in the database. Although I am also noting that this output only shows at initialisation of `runserver`, not when the form page is accessed.

One final point, the user is authenticated and editing their own record.

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and even more error, and some wide-ranging searching, I found the answer via the documentation at https://ccbv.co.uk/.

Essentially the path I decided to take was to use a different `form` for the respective fields that I wanted to use (I'm sure there are other solutions out there that add or subtract fields from the views). This involved changing the `form_class` with `get_form_class`:

```
# views.py
class telephone_view(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'account/telephone.html'
    #no need to define "form_class" here
    #form_class = TelephoneForm
    success_url = '/accounts/telephone/'

    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.request.user.profile.status == 'managed':
            messages.success(self.request, _('you got the managed form'))
            return TelephoneFormExtended
        else:
            messages.success(self.request, _('you got the other form'))
            return TelephoneFormLight

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Profile.get_or_create_for_user(self.request.user)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, _('Your telephone setting was updated'))
        return super(telephone_view, self).form_valid(form)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(telephone_view, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

After working it out for myself I also found this answer which does the same thing:
[Updateview with dynamic form_class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965341/updateview-with-dynamic-form-class)